# foreach char in string

Tags: java, javascript, html, css

I'm trying to achieve the below Java selection in Javascript, and I'm a little stumped at the moment...

Java:

```
String input = inputField.getText();

foreach (char c: input.toCharArray()){
    input = input.replace('a','1');
    input = input.replace('b','2');
    //and so on...
}
return input;
}
```

This is what I've tried:

```
var input = document.getElementById('inputField').value; //input field is textarea

for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    for(input.charAt(i)){
        input = input.replace('a','1');
        input = input.replace('b','2');
    }
}
return input;
}
```

I've also tried some different variations, such as disregarding the loop entirely and just using replace; however, then the replaces will just fire off sequentially and will not cover the length of long multi spaced strings.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your code (java one) doesn't make any sense to me. Same as replacing all chars to 'z'

Comment: Are you trying achieve something like a [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)?

Comment: My Java code summed up. "For every character in this string; replace x character with y character and return it" I've ran my Java code before and it works for what I need it to do. I just need to write a ha equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `replace` function in JavaScript just replaces the first occurrence. A similar post is [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript).

What you should use is RegExp:

```
s = 'abcabc';
s = s.replace(/a/g, 'b');
```

Check out the code here: [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/yrokxrd4/).

Answer (score 0):

As realUser404 said, your code doesn't do what you want to to do anyway.

Here is, what I assume you want (incrementing each char in the string by 1), in Javascript.

```js
var inputString = "abcdefg",
    outputString = "";

for (var i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
    outputString += String.fromCharCode(inputString.charCodeAt(i) + 1);
}
```

Comment: It is not an `int i`. In JavaScript, it is a `var i`.